# PHP: extend existing class

Tags: php, oop

Is it possible to set the parent of the class? I.e. an instance of the parent class gets instantiated during runtime and then a child class instance extending a certain parent instance gets created. For example:

```
class A {
    var $test = 'default';
}

class B extends A {
    public function __contsruct(A $a) {
        parent = $a; //does not work
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->test = 'changed';
$b = new B($a);
$b->test == 'changed'; //should be true
```

I know that I could just `$b = new B(); $b->test = 'changed'`, but that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: No, this is not possible. But depending on the exact problem you are trying to solve there might be other ways to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've asked for is not possible in base PHP.  There are a few ways to do similar things.

You could use the highly experimental [runkit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) extension.  The [runkit_class_emancipate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-class-emancipate.php) and [runkit_class_adopt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-class-adopt.php) functions should work.  However, they operate on entire classes, not instances of a class.  This probably limits their usefulness for your application.

If you're trying to emulate the expandable class features of other languages, like Ruby and Perl, [runkit_method_add](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-add.php) and related functions might be more suitable.  Again, however, it still operates on entire classes.

The normally accepted "PHP way" to do things like this is via [__call](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods).  In fact, with [anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in 5.3, you can do something like...

```
class Bar {
    public function say($thing) {
        echo "Bar::say says: $thing\n";
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar {
    private $extensions = array();

    public function addExtension($func_name, $func) {
        $this->extensions[ $func_name ] = $func;
    }

    public function __call($func_name, $arguments) {
        array_unshift($arguments, $this);
        if(array_key_exists($func_name, $this->extensions))
            call_user_func_array($this->extensions[ $func_name ], $arguments);
    }
}

$f = new Foo();
$anon = function($obj, $string){ $obj->say($string); };
$f->addExtension('example', $anon);
$f->example("Hello, world!");
```

You'll note in __call and that in creating the anonymous function that the first argument becomes the instance.  That's because PHP 5.3's implementation of anonymous functions can't reference `$this`.  That also means that they can't reference protected or private members of the class.  This can be corrected by cloning the instance and using [Reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to expose the protected and private members.  See [this comment on the anonymous function manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#98384) for an example implementation.

Because of limitations of PHP, you can't directly assign an anonymous function to a property and call it.  This example will not work:

```
class WillNotWork {
    public $fatal_error;
}

$broken = new WillNotWork();
$anon = function($arg) { echo "I'm about to create a {$arg} error!"; };
$broken->fatal_error = $anon;
$broken->fatal_error("fatal");
// Fatal error: Call to undefined method WillNotWork::fatal_error()
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to accomplish this is like so:

```
class Foo
{
    function __construct() {
        $this->hello = "Hello";
    }

    public function sayHello() {
        echo $this->hello."!";
    }
}

class Bar
{
    function __construct(&$foo) {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function sayHelloAgain() {
        echo $this->foo->sayHello()." Again!";
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo->sayHello(); //outputs "Hello!"

$bar = new Bar($foo);
echo $bar->sayHelloAgain(); //outputs "Hello! Again!"
```

Comment: Interesting solution, worth to try. Also You don't need `&$foo`. `$foo` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

No, because `$a` is a separate instance than `$b`.